# PSACCESSLOG - Need a SQL query that will provide distinct logins per day

Tags: peoplesoft-query

PSACCESSLOG - I need a SQL query that will provide distinct logins per day.

I am struggling with the date time formats and grouping by day.

This is my current query

```
SELECT  
    CAST(LOGINDTTM AS date) AS "Date", 
    COUNT(DISTINCT OPRID) AS NumOPRs
FROM
    PSACCESSLOG  A
WHERE 
    TO_CHAR(((A.LOGINDTTM ) + ( 0)),'YYYY-MM-DD') >= '2024-03-01'
GROUP BY
    CAST(LOGINDTTM AS date)
ORDER BY 
    "Date"
```

This query results in many entries under the date 2024-03-01. I am looking for a total number for that date. Not sure what I am doing wrong

Comment: Can you give an example output? If you mean the result is a "Date" 2024-03-01 with NumOPRs larger than 1, then it means there are more than 1 ORPID logged in on the specified date. There is nothing wrong with that. And you need to include the information such as what database vendor is it. (I guess it is Oracle, but it would be better if you provide the information if you want other people to help you.)